# Complement method for .last when working with List objects?

Tags: scala

Working with Lists in Scala I would like a simple way to get all elements but the last element. Is there a complementary method for .last similar to .head/.tail complement?

I'd rather not dirty up code with something like:

```
    val x: List[String] = List("abc", "def", "ghi")
    val allButLast: List[String] = x.reverse.tail.reverse
    // List(abc, def)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for all of the responses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`init` selects all elements but the last one.

List API for [init](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List@init:Repr).

```
scala> List(1,2,3,4,5)
res0: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

scala> res0.init
res1: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Comment: Be aware that `init` on a list does not allow for structural sharing. So it completely recreates a new list. Hence, it is also `O(n)`, rather than `O(1)`.

Answer (score 4):

The 4 related methods here are `head`, `tail`, `init`, and `last`.

`head` and `last` get the first and final member, whereas
`tail` and `init` exclude the first and final members.

```
scala> val list = (0 to 10).toList
list: List[Int] = List(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)

scala> list.head
res0: Int = 0

scala> list.tail
res1: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)

scala> list.init
res2: List[Int] = List(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)

scala> list.last
res3: Int = 10
```

You should also take care, because all 4 of them are unsafe on the empty list and will throw exceptions.

These methods are defined on [GenTraversableLike](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.collection.GenTraversableLike), which List implements.

Answer (score 2):

That's `init`.

link to Scaladoc: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List@init:Repr

> `def init: List[A]`
>
> Selects all elements except the last.

Also, note that it's defined in `GenTraversableLike`, so pretty much any Scala collection has this method.

Answer (score 1):

For *dropping* off any number of items from the end of a list consider `dropRight`,

```
val xs = (1 to 5).toList

xs.dropRight(1)
List(1, 2, 3, 4)

xs.dropRight(2)
List(1, 2, 3)

xs.dropRight(10)
List()
```